# Is there a way to "signal" type narrowing to TypeScript from an earlier null/undefined check?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm loading a few environment variables into my Node & Express app using `dotenv` and a lot of these values are critical to the app's function so before doing anything I validate these variables to make sure they're included and that they have the correct type, otherwise I throw an error and stop the server from starting.

I now need to use these variables down the line, but TypeScript does not recognize that I have narrowed the types so it prevents me from doing things like `process.env.test.includes` (without optional chaining or nearby type assertion) saying `Object is possibly null or undefined` (I have strict mode enabled). I know in some cases it'll recognize that I have narrowed the type if I do type checks but I'm guessing this is not nearby enough to the code for it to pick up on this. Is there any way to signal that I have already narrowed the type from `string | null | undefined` to just `string`, for example, or do I have to continue to use the optional chaining operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [non-null assertion operator `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to tell TypeScript that you know better, that it should never be null/undefined:

```
process!.env!.test!.includes
```

This is of course assuming that any of the keys in the chain could return null/undefined, but you probably don't need to use the operator on every single accessor.

Comment: Ah ok these don't end up in the compiled code right? So it at least saves a few conditional checks in production. I was mostly hoping that there would be an annotation or something similar but at least this is a small improvement over optional chaining

Comment: Nope. It simply hints typescript that you know better than the compiler, that it shouldn't be null/undefined :) it will never appear in emitted code.

Comment: Btw, as a side note, do user-defined type guards have any significant advantages? I'm also validating various request bodies in different places and I'm trying to determine whether it's worth defining an interface for each and converting my validation function to a generic

Comment: Sometimes user-defined type guards work, but sometimes TypeScript is unable to narrow the type due to your interfaces/types being overly convoluted. The non-null assertion operator is often a last-resort escape hatch :) but if it works, it works.

Comment: Ok awesome, I think non-null assertion is perfect for this case as in my code I'll never run into a case where these values are null/undefined so I just need to appease TypeScript here